# How to set Full Height of Parent Element to Text Area in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, textarea

I have a text area inside a VBox but its not taking the full height. Do you guys have any idea on how to fix this?

```
final TextArea htmlCode = new TextArea();
htmlCode.setWrapText(true);
htmlCode.prefHeightProperty().bind(<parentConrol>.prefHeightProperty());
```

Hope not to bother.

Comment: `VBox.setVgrow(htmlCode, Priority.ALWAYS)`.

Comment: If possible, can you add an answer to accept it as the solution?. Thanks!

Comment: Since this question was (justifiably) closed as a duplicate I can't post an answer.